# Same SQL queries giving different output in PostgreSQL and NodeJS with Date

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have created a table that has column date_of_creation as Date:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  last_name VARCHAR,
  date_of_creation DATE
}
```

Now when I tried run the query:

```
SELECT * from user;
//output date_of_creation : 2021-03-07
```

But when I run same query from nodejs using pg library, it returns the output like this:

```
date_of_creation : 2021-03-06T23:00:00.000Z,
```

I do not understood where it is going wrong and why.

Comment: A time zone is being applied. What does `show timezone;` return in `psql`? How are you pulling the data out using the `pg` library?

Comment: timezone: etc/UTC; In pg library I am pulling the data like: pool.query(SELECT * from user);

Comment: `etc/UTC` is the system timezone. `show timezone;`  will return the time zone as set in the server.

Comment: `TimeZone
----------
 Etc/UTC
(1 row)`, this is what I am getting for `show timezone;`

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. So what is the time zone where the Javascript is running?